# How to specify number of branch in decision tree in R

Tags: r, decision-tree, rpart

I'am using decision tree to predict future behavior of my dataset.It contains decision variable called "rate" That I want to predict.I have many characteristics that influences on the rate column but when I apply decision tree algorithm. I gave only one level which is ibt as mentioned on the code below:

```
ad.apprentissage= rpart(rate~vqs+ibt+tbt+bf+n, data=filteredDataFinal)

node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
      * denotes terminal node

1) root 27 15 4 (0.4074074 0.4444444 0.1481481)  
  2) ibt< 1.516 11  3 3 (0.7272727 0.2727273 0.0000000) *
  3) ibt>=1.516 16  7 4 (0.1875000 0.5625000 0.2500000) *
```

Now, I'm asking on how to add other level to the tree like tbt characteristics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing your question, but tree size in rpart is controlled by the complexity parameter (cp).  You can try different values to get a different sized tree.

```
ad.apprentissage= rpart(rate~vqs+ibt+tbt+bf+n, data=filteredDataFinal, cp=0.1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it minsplit who it is responsible for tree length

Comment: Right, minsplit will also influence the number of splits, but in general the number of splits increases with decreasing cp.  (BTW, I just realized the default cp is 0.01, so you'll need to go lower than this to see more splits in your tree).